# Quadratic Diophantine Equation with Rational Coefficients

Tags: diophantine-equations

The problem is as below:

> Solve all solutions to $x^2+\dfrac{p}{q}(xy)+y^2=z^2$ for $x$, $y$, $z\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $p$, $q\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd{(p,q)}=1$.

**My attempt:** Noticing that for a Diophantine Equation $x^2+axy+y^2$, it's solution is given by:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
x&=k(an^2-2mn) \\
y&=k(m^2-n^2) \\
z&=k(amn-m^2-n^2). \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

By multiplying the whole equation with $q^2$ gives $(qx)^2+pqxy+(qy)^2=(qz)^2$. And I'm stuck from here.

---

Can someone please help? This seems like an interesting problem.

Comment: after "Noticing that,"  what is it that $x^2 + axy + y^2$ is being set equal to????

Comment: I see, you give an explicit formula for $z,$ so somebody told you that all solutions to $x^2 + axy+ y^2 = z^2$ are given that way. Who told you that?

Comment: @WillJagy Oops, sorry, it should be $z^2$.

Comment: @WillJagy http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823199/quadratic-diophantine-equation-x2-axy-y2-z2?rq=1

Comment: I requested one of the Andreescu and Dorin books, their 2015 book   ***Quadratic Diophantine Equations*** rather than the 2010 one mentioned in that earlier question. It is a theorem that the integer solutions of $x^2 + a xy + y^2 - z^2 = 0$ is made up from a finite number of formulas such as you list; for now, I do not see why there is only one.

Comment: For this particular solution the following formula.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225175/structure-of-x2-xy-y2-z2-integer-quadratic-form/732648#732648  The General formula is.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513733/solving-a-diophantine-equation-of-the-form-x2-ay2-byz-cz2-with-the-co/1514030#1514030

Comment: blast, you have an answer here that is worth examning. Meanwhile, the earlier question has an erroneous claim that people are taking without question, see my new http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823199/quadratic-diophantine-equation-x2-axy-y2-z2/1912677#1912677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2+\dfrac{p}{q}(xy)+y^2=z^2$$

---

Let $X = \dfrac xz$ and $Y = \dfrac yz$.

$qX^2 + pXY + qY^2 =q$

A solution is $(X, Y) = (1,0)$

So consider a solution of the form
$$Y = \dfrac st( X - 1)$$

a line with rational slope which passes through a known solution.

We find\begin{align}
  qX^2 + pXY + qY^2 &= q  \\
  qX^2 + p \dfrac st X(X - 1) + q\dfrac{s^2}{t^2}(X^2 - 2X + 1) &= q
\\
  \left( q + p \dfrac st + q\dfrac{s^2}{t^2} \right)X^2
  + \left(-p\dfrac st - 2q\dfrac{s^2}{t^2}\right)X + 
  \left( q\dfrac{s^2}{t^2} - q \right) &= 0
\\
  (qt^2 + pst + qs^2)X^2 + (-pst - 2qs^2)X + (qs^2 - qt^2) &= 0
\end{align}

We know that $X = 1$ is a solution. So $X-1$ must be a factor. Dividing by $X-1$ we get
$(qt^2 + pst + qs^2)X + (qt^2 - qs^2) = 0$

So $X = \dfrac{qs^2 - qt^2}{qs^2 + pst + qt^2}$
and $Y = \dfrac{-ps^2 - 2qst}{qs^2 + pst + qt^2}$

Hence $(x,y,z) = (qs^2 - qt^2, -ps^2 - 2qst, qs^2 + pst + qt^2)$

Comment: Where coefficient $q$ near $Y$?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov - Thanks. I hope I made the appropriate corrections.

Comment: @StevenGregory Now our answers matched up to a permutation $x,y.$

Comment: These are not always primitive; please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823199/quadratic-diophantine-equation-x2-axy-y2-z2/1912677#1912677

Answer (score 0):

$$qx^2+pxy+qy^2=qz^2$$

$$x=(2qk-pt)t$$

$$y=q(t^2-k^2)$$

$$z=qk^2-pkt+qt^2$$

Comment: Can you give an easy proof to the answer? Thanks for the reply anyways!

Comment: @blastzit  I do not understand.  What proof? Identity is performed - this is enough.

Comment: But how can you know that every $x$, $y$ and $z$ are in this form?

Comment: @blastzit  To do this, there is a general formula. To prove this we have to use it.  Still will not use it. So that does not need any proof.

Answer (score 0):

We can use formula
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
x&=k(an^2-2mn) \\
y&=k(m^2-n^2) \\
z&=k(amn-m^2-n^2). \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
with 
$$a=\dfrac pq,\quad k=lq,$$
then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
x&=l(pn^2-2mnq) \\
y&=lq(m^2-n^2) \\
z&=l(pmn-m^2q-n^2q). \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: the solutions you give need not include all primitive solutions: please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823199/quadratic-diophantine-equation-x2-axy-y2-z2/1912677#1912677