# Find all integer pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a^2+ab+b^2=219^2$, without technology.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, quadratics, square-numbers

Find all integer pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a^2+ab+b^2=219^2$, without technology.

My colleague showed me this question. He said it is from the AIME (American Invitational Mathematics Examination).

I regarded the equation as a quadratic in $b$, so
$$b=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{438^2-3a^2}}{2}$$
so $438^2-3a^2$ must be a square number. Without technology, I have not found a nice way to find all possible values of $a$.

EDIT: I don't know if this helps, but if we ignore the bit about "without technology", then using excel we can find that the solutions are:

> $\pm(0, 219), \pm(51, 189), \pm(51, -240), \pm(189,-240), (219, -219)$ and their inverses.

EDIT2:  My colleague, to my annoyance, just told me that the *whole question* was this: A triangle has side lengths $a, b, 219$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers. The angle opposite the side of length $219$ is $120°$. Find $a$ and $b$.

I apologize for posting an incomplete, possibly unsolvable, question and thus wasting readers' time. In future, when posting questions that I get from other people, I will be more careful to avoid the [X-Y problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Having said that, I am still interested in whether the original version of the question is solvable.

Comment: What does "without technology" mean ? Without electronic help ? Or without advanced methods ?

Comment: @Peter "Without technology" means no calculator, no computer. Pen and paper only. Is there a standard way of expressing this?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that. I do not think that there is a common name for this, I usually call it "without electronic help". Most users call it "without a calculator".

Comment: Well, working $\pmod 9$ you see that $3$ divides both $a,b$.  Thus you can "simplify" to the equation $A^2+AB+B^2=73^2$.  Might help.  It reduces your $438$ to the more tractable $146$.

Comment: You can multiply with $4$ and write the new equation as $(2a+b)^2+3b^2=438^2$. Even if we use lulu's hint however, there are still a lot numbers to check. To be honest, I have no idea, but surely someone on this site will find a "surprisingly easy" solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with the ring of [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer)? It is (norm) Euclidean so a UFD, which makes problems like this easy.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225175/structure-of-x2-xy-y2-z2-integer-quadratic-form/732648#732648

Comment: Hint: Use the formula $ (a^2 + 3b^2)(c^2 + 3d^2) = (ac+3bd)^2 + 3 (ac-bd)^2$.  $\quad$ Rewrite the equation as $ (a+2b)^2 + 3a^2 = (2 \times 3 \times 73)^2$. So, we just need to find solution for individual terms, them multiply them.

Comment: @CalvinLin   see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#Integer_triangles_with_a_120.C2.B0_angle  a primitive triple $u^2 + uv + v^2 = w^2 $  is $u=m^2-n^2, \; \; $    $ v = 2mn + n^2, \; \; $  $ w = m^2 + mn + n^2. \; \; $   so we just need $73 = m^2 + mn + n^2 .$  This is also what happens if we  investigate Gauss composition for $x^2 +xy + y^2 .$  All very, very similar to Pythagorean Triples...  In case of interest, see page 47, Theorem 4, in Mordell, Diophantine Equations.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes I'm aware of that (and they are related) . I was thinking of it as "how does a high school student doing the AIME approach this, esp if they don't have the pre-knowledge of those group theory results?". Though I guess i'm missing the "how do you know you got all pairs".

Comment: @BillDubuque OK, but since this question is from the AIME, which is for high school students, I'm wondering if there is solution that high school students could be expected to find.

Comment: @CalvinLin  it occurs to me that part of collecting all solutions can be written as Vieta Jumping.  Expressing 73  with positive (8,1)   jumps to (-9,1)  or (9,-1).  Just a thought.

Comment: Nice that Excel is so powerful :) But I prefer software tools like PARI/GP for such tasks. Also, please avoid spoilers in questions, they make sense in answers perhaps, but surely not in a question.

Comment: @Peter OK, but I wonder where else I could have put the technology-found solutions. I wanted to put them in a spoiler because I thought some readers would want to see them and some readers would not want to see them. I didn't put them in an answer, because I didn't think they constitute an answer.